# Ibm analytics user logging data to DashDB, then sent to Watson Analytics

Tags: ibm-cloud, analytics, ibm-mobile-services, dashdb

My name is Cristian and my task is to implement IBM Bluemix Analytics into an app (which was succesfull, since I get the data shown on my analytics service), then how do I transfer this data for every user into DashDB, and then into Watson Analytics?

Sincerely, 
Cristian Sandu

Comment: You probably want to check out the dashDB for Analytics documentation to see if this service gets you to your end goal: https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/dashDB/dashDB.html#dashDB

Comment: Incidentally, the dashDB for Analytics service has been renamed Db2 Warehouse on Cloud. See: https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/07/ibm-dashdb-analytics-now-db2-warehouse-cloud/

Answer (score 1):

To answer the latter half of your question, you can import it into Watson Analytics [via these steps](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4QC9/com.ibm.solutions.wa_an_overview.2.0.0.doc/wa_an_hlp_crt_db_data_dw.html)

You'll need a 'Professional' level subscription to access the 'Create a new Connection' page (what you get with the 30 day free trial).

Answer (score 1):

Watson Analytics allows you to create multiple data connection and select particular data from columns and add it to a single database.

You can not only do that, you can shape the data before you import, so if different connections have a variety of data arrangements, it helps you streamline into the same format.

Quick procedure is mentioned here in the [IBM Watson Analytics Knowledgebase](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS4QC9/com.ibm.solutions.wa_an_overview.2.0.0.doc/wa_an_hlp_crt_db_data_dw.html)

And yes, you will not get these feature in the LITE version of Watson Analytics.